# How to Perform Payment Refund in Payum bundle using stripe and Paypal?

Tags: payum

i would like to do the Payment Refund using Payum Bundle, how can i do payment refund with Stripe and Paypal  using Payum bundle?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This feature was not implemented yet. Where in theory it is easy to implement (1-2 days).

What has to be done:

You have to create payum's request: `RefundRequest` and two payum's actions which support the request (can manage it). In the action you have to put payment specific refund logic. It may require some changes in statuses as refund status is not present yet too.

The refund action can be added to the bundle to ease future use.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply @Maksim.
if I understand what you explained here then it may work like below.

1. I have to create `RefundRequest` like `CaptureRequest`.

2. I have to Create Action `RefundAction` Like  `CaptureAction`.

3. I have to add new method in `TokenFactory`  Class Which calls the `RefundAction`.
is it a correct Step which i have to follow?

Comment: Yes, it is correct one. You may also need a refund controller (in terms of symfony). That may handle refund request. The token factory then create a token for this controller

Comment: i got the way but when i insert SecuredRefundRequest() in Request it gives me error 
`Request SecuredRefundRequest{model: ArrayObject} is not supported.`
can you please help me how can i solve it?

Comment: There should be an action that can process (other words execute it) the request. For example if you want execute CaptureRequest there is a [Paypal CaptureAction](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/src/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/Action/CaptureAction.php) or [Be2bill Capture Action](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/src/Payum/Be2Bill/Action/CaptureAction.php).